# Is there a font with 3px max width

Tags: fonts

[image]
I would like to feed my led matrix display (with round leds) with a font that uses max. 3 pixel in width per letter.

How would I create such a font, that is still readeable?

I think the biggest problem would be the "w" (but maybe use a trick to the eye for this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use an 8x3 bitmap dataset instead of a real font? Something like a `W` on an 8x3 can be encoded in a few ways, just add a tiny vertical to act as visual middling (same for `M`):

```
x   x   x x x   x       x x x   x x x   x   x   x x x
x   x   x       x       x       x   x   x x x   x     
x   x   x       x       x       x   x   x x x   x    
x   x   x x x   x       x       x   x   x   x   x x x
x x x   x       x       x       x   x   x   x   x    
x x x   x       x       x       x   x   x   x   x    
x   x   x x x   x x x   x x x   x x x   x   x   x x x
```